# Creating a copy of MailItem and then deleting creates a new mail in the same folder

Tags: outlook-addin

I created a copy of a mail in my Inbox folder by calling MailItem.copy() function and then I deleted the newly created mail item.

Following is sample code:

```
IDispatch * lDispatch;
_MailItemPtr lReadModeMailItem;
HRESULT lReturn = mMailItem->Copy(&lDispatch);
if (lReturn != S_OK)
{
    return;
}

lReturn = lDispatch->QueryInterface(IID__MailItem, (LPVOID*)&lReadModeMailItem);
if (lReturn != S_OK || lReadModeMailItem == NULL)
{
    return;
}

lReadModeMailItem->Close(olDiscard);

HRESULT lMyRet = lReadModeMailItem->Delete();
if (lMyRet != S_OK)
{
    return;
}
lDispatch->Release();
```

After I am done executing this code, 2 new mail items are created in my Inbox folder.
Then, if I move to any other folder and come back to Inbox or restart Outlook, then 1 new mail item remains.

Why does 1 extra mail item remain in Inbox, even when I called MailItem.Delete() function?
How can I permanently delete the mail item created using MailItem.Copy() ?

Comment: Is this an IMAP4 store?

Comment: Yes, it is an IMAP account.

Comment: IMAP4 provider is infamous for its problems, one of them ghost items created when an existing item is edited.

Comment: Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0):

That's the lack of IMAP accounts in Outlook.

You may consider using the following workarounds to get rid of such issues:

1. Programmatically switch folders in Outlook by setting the `Explorer.CurrentFolder` property which allows setting a Folder object that represents the current folder displayed in the explorer.
2. Use the [SyncObject.Start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/syncobject-start-method-outlook) method which begins synchronizing a user's folders using the specified Send\Receive group.